# not getting the output of hello world in vs code output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not getting the hello world message on the output screen I installed nodejs and coderunner

[image: hello world is not getting on output]

Comment: You should open "Terminal" tab and run the `node ...` command there, – you'll see the output

Comment: Did you try looking in the "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab?

Comment: i tried but not working and there is a message aka.ms\powershell and I already installed powershell.so what should I do

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the file to execute.

1. Go to terminal(present alongside of output tab, you currently opened screen)
2. `node Origin.js`
   You will get the output.

Edited:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows `[Running] node "c:\Users\Cyntexia\Desktop\js\Origin.js"`

Comment: Above comment edited. Please refer the screenshot.

Comment: tq for response i tried it but it is not working...the following is appearing in the terminal tab
PowerShell 7.2.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\Users\Cyntexia\Desktop\js> node origin.js
PS C:\Users\Cyntexia\Desktop\js>